# Do any Lutheran denominations (or parachurch reform groups) successfully represent "repristination theology"?

Tags: church-history, exegesis, lutheranism

A [Tweet](https://twitter.com/franzpieper/status/368039928052977664) by some fans of [Franz Pieper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Pieper) recently said,

> God has blessed the "repristination theology" of our fathers with success also in this country. #lcms #lutheran

Growing up in Lutheranism, that was the first time I'd ever heard the term.

[Britannica](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/498536/Repristination-Theology) defines it as:

> “The Repristination Theology” (i.e., restoration of earlier norms), led by Ernst Wilhelm Hengstenberg (1802–69), made 17th-century orthodoxy normative for the interpretation of Luther’s teachings and fought the rising historical-critical approach to the Bible by affirming the verbal inspiration...

Do any Lutheran denominations (or parachurch reform groups) successfully represent "repristination theology"?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia's Neo-Lutheranism article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Lutheranism#Repristination_versus_Erlangen_school), repristination theology beget Confessional Lutheranism.  There are two major churches in America which describe themselves as "Confessional Lutherans."  They are the Lutheran Church - Missouri Synod and the Wisconsin Evangelical Lutheran Synod.

[A Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelical_Lutheran_Church_in_America#ELCA_and_LC-MS) lists some (albeit debateable) differences between non-Confessional and Confessional Lutheranism.